# Glass not rendering correctly

Tags: transparency, glass

I've no idea where this grey is coming from. Transmission 1.0 and Roughness 0

[image: Weird Reflection,Originally thought my glass was thick but it isn't]

[image: Opaque from the inside]

[image: Silver Metallic Reflection]

Comment: Because you didn't put thing around your platform. That's Blender default **empty** been rendered.

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix! Apparently my normals were facing the wrong way. You can check this by clicking on overlays and checking "Face Orientation"; Red means it is reversed. I Selected all my vertices and hit shift-n and voila no more silvery things! Thank you everyone who gave suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is reflecting the world texture. Try changing the color of the world as represented below and see if the reflection of the cup remains grey.

[image]

Another suggestion, change the IOR of your glass texture. This is related to the degree of the glass, like the ones we use in the face. Try putting it into 1 and it will show the object inside without any distortion.

Hope it helps :)
[image]

Comment: It is definitely reflecting the world but no color value can help me make the glass completely clean, I tried making the world color alpha 0 but still the grey persists. Changing the IOR value to 1 makes my glass completely invisible.

Comment: Oh man, sorry then :( If you find the answer, please post it here. I'm also curious on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely try `@Mateus Arruda`'s answer first. If that doesn't work, try turning down the Alpha on that same node.
[image]

Comment: Changing the Alpha definitely helps with the weird reflections but it makes my glass itself more transparent and even a middle value looks unnatural.

Comment: A combination of the two? Try turning the "Transmission" value up. Mess with IOR, Transmission, Transmission Roughness and Alpha until you get the right setup.